# Upload image using POST, php and Android

Tags: java, android, entity

I am getting the following error message after trying to upload an image using a MultipartEntity in android:

```
Error: Problem with [picture] (File upload error 4)
```

I am using the following code to upload the image:

```
String url = "http://www.uploadurl.com/api/files.php";
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

MultipartEntity multiEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Temp/" +  IMAGE_FILENAME);

ContentBody cBody = new FileBody(file);

StringBody sb1 = new StringBody(getNameFormatted());
StringBody sb2 = new StringBody(getDeviceID());

MultipartEntity multipartContent = new MultipartEntity();
multipartContent.addPart("name", sb1);
multipartContent.addPart("uuid", sb2);
multipartContent.addPart("picture", cBody);

httpPost.setEntity(multipartContent); 

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
```

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong, I have uploaded images using code very similar to this in the past only using a JSON array as a part of the entity rather than adding all of them individually. I think it's got something to do with the way the image is set into its ContentBody maybe? I'm really not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: [Android file uploader with server-side php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204476/android-file-uploader-with-server-side-php)