# trouble in upload data android

Tags: android

i need to upload audio file(or any File) in server. i have asp.net server and refer this code but as per my doubt it is code of PHP server uploading.but i need to do in asp.net. so what is the changes to apply ?

one more thing is url liook like this :: http://xyz/MRESC/images/CustomizeActivity/193/ so its not store in Database it store in directory

**Update ::**

```
package com.upload;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HttpFileUploader extends Activity {
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);

     HttpURLConnection connection = null;
     DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
     DataInputStream inputStream = null;

     //String pathToOurFile = "/sdcard/audiometer/shanesh1599870.mp3";
     String pathToOurFile = "http://www.deviantart.com/download/78789749/Gohan_Jr__by_android_1.jpg";
     //String urlServer = "http://asd/MRESC/images/CustomizeActivity/193/";
     upLoad2Server(pathToOurFile);
 }



 public static int upLoad2Server(String sourceFileUri) {
      String upLoadServerUri = "http://xyz/MRESC/images/CustomizeActivity/193/";
      // String [] string = sourceFileUri;
      String fileName = sourceFileUri;

      HttpURLConnection conn = null;
      DataOutputStream dos = null;
      DataInputStream inStream = null;
      String lineEnd = "\r\n";
      String twoHyphens = "--";
      String boundary = "*****";
      int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
      byte[] buffer;
      int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
      String responseFromServer = "";

      File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
      if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
       return 0;
      }
      int serverResponseCode = 0;
    try { // open a URL connection to the Servlet
       FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
       URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
       conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
       conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
       conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
       conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
       conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
       conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
       conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
       conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
       conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);
       dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

       dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
       dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""+ fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
       dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

       bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); // create a buffer of  maximum size
       Log.i("Huzza", "Initial .available : " + bytesAvailable);

       bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
       buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

       // read file and write it into form...
       bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

       while (bytesRead > 0) {
        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
         bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
         bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

       // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
       dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
       dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

       // Responses from the server (code and message)
       serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
       String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

       Log.i("Upload file to server", "HTTP Response is : " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);
       // close streams
       Log.i("Upload file to server", fileName + " File is written");
       fileInputStream.close();
       dos.flush();
       dos.close();
      } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
       Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
      } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
    //this block will give the response of upload link
      try {
       BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn
         .getInputStream()));
       String line;
       while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        Log.i("Huzza", "RES Message: " + line);
       }
       rd.close();
      } catch (IOException ioex) {
       Log.e("Huzza", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
      }
      return serverResponseCode;  // like 200 (Ok)

     } // end upLoad2Server


}
```

Permission ::

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To upload a file on server I don't think so for asp .net and PHP server have a different code on android.**

```
Just check your server side script. For android both are treated as a server (either a asp .net or PHP).
```

I don't know PHP or asp .net but take a look at these examples,

1. [How to upload a file using Java HttpClient library working with PHP - strange problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067655/how-to-upload-a-file-using-java-httpclient-library-working-with-php-strange-pr)
2. [HTTP Post multipart file upload in Java ME](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/HTTP_Post_multipart_file_upload_in_Java_ME)
3. [Upload image using POST, php and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622003/upload-image-using-post-php-and-android)
4. [Java Swing File upload with Php on the server](http://www.einfobuzz.com/2011/09/upload-file-using-java-swing-and-php.html)
5. http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

In these, there are some example for java swing or java ME but I think just use the logic for upload file from java and then take look at how they handle on server side with php script.

Comment: can you elaborate that how can i check server side script?

Comment: one more thing is that i dont know what parameter should i pass in all  `setRequestProperty` content. see my code.

Comment: one more thing is url liook like this :: `http://xyz/MRESC/images/CustomizeActivity/193/` so its not store in Database it store in directory.

Comment: In my case I put image in MultipartEntity set as a filebody and then in URL give the server's php script's url path.