# Sending pictures from android device to server

Tags: java, android

im trying to send a picture from a android device to a server and was wondering if it was possible to send the picture information in a xml file and rebuild it on the server?

Comment: <a href="http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/">This blog</a> helped is significantly with this. Also there's <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204476/android-file-uploader-with-server-side-php">this</a> and <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935946/sending-images-using-http-post">this</a>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is, you just have to use Base64 to encode and decode the file stream. To encode you'll use the **android.util.Base64** class and at the server side (if you're also using Java) you can use the [commons-codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) Base64 class.

The idea would be build the xml file as with whatever tool you would like to:

```
<image>
  <user>username</user>
  <other-property>property</other-property>
  <data><-- here you'll add your base64 encoded image as a string -->
</image>
```

Once you do this, just upload the XML file itself to your server and parse the XML file in there.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [MultiPartPost](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods/multipartpost.html). This SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038409/how-to-send-http-post-request-and-recieve-response/3038747#3038747) is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you can user `Base64`to send your image as text, so you can put in xml file