# Passing paramaters using NameValuePair

Tags: java, android

I have the application to take the photo and send it to server. The taking photo and server(accept image) run perfectly separately. When I try to use below code after taking photo to send server, it causes to force to close the application. Here is the code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
      Uri imageUri=data.getData();
      List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
      params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", imageUri.getPath()));
      post("http://myserver-address",params);
   }
}
```

post method is same as [Sending images using Http Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935946/sending-images-using-http-post)

Log cat says:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity
{com.john.smith/com.john.smith.Activity}: java.lang.RuntimeException:
Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null}
to activity {com.john.smith/com.john.smith.Activity}:
   java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I think, there is something wrong for passing parameters to send function. Because, I try disable all the lines in my send function, still face the error. And this error causes to force the application close.

How can I fix that problem ? How to pass the photo to `send` function other than mine ?

**Update:**

my camera capture code is same as 
http://code.google.com/p/crw-cmu/source/browse/luis/PhotoIntentActivity/src/com/example/android/photobyintent/PhotoIntentActivity.java?r=734

I call it like that

```
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

        switch (requestCode) {
        case ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            handleBigCameraPhoto();
          Uri imageUri=data.getData();
          List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
          params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", imageUri.getPath()));
          post("http://myserver-address",params);
        }
            }
            break;
        } // ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B

    } // switch
}
```

Comment: Check if `imageUri` is null after this line `Uri imageUri=data.getData();`.  Also, what's in `handleBigCameraPhoto`?

Comment: I checked Uri imageUri=data.getData(); and it does return null, How to get the image that captured from camera ?

Answer (score 0):

The log show `data=null` so `Uri imageUri=data.getData();` cause a NPE.

I suggest to add some `if( requestCode == ...) {` or `switch( requestCode )` because the data is not set in all the cases.

To avoid a crash you should check for null before dereferencing `data` and `imageUri`. Add some log in the `else` clauses.

An Internet search provides results:

- http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/25/android-upload-an-image-to-a-server (good)
- [Sending pictures to a web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415390/sending-pictures-to-a-web-server)
- [Sending images using Http Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935946/sending-images-using-http-post) (best)
- [Sending pictures from android device to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850325/sending-pictures-from-android-device-to-server)

Comment: Yes, you are right, When I try to use imageUri, it returns null. So, how can I get the image that captured from the camera and send it to send function.

Comment: I applied your suggestion, the thing is that my imageUri is always null because, data comes null. So, how to fix it ?

Comment: I have a question, this code 'params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", imageUri.getPath()));' sends the path of the image not the image itself, Right ?

Comment: Okay, thanks. I already saw these links. I choose the best one as you highlighted. Now, the question turns into that Where should I call the post function, it seems calling in "onActivityResult" not good. ?