# how to open sdcard memory and select pdf file to get its path for uploading it in android

Tags: android

I want to upload a file which is stored in sdcard to php server.To upload a file i need the filepath.When i am giving the path in application my file is getting uploaded to php server.For this i have used code from following url [Android file uploader with server-side php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204476/android-file-uploader-with-server-side-php) and it working nice.But here the path is given in source code only.But i donot want to give the path in my application.I want to open the sdcard and then select the file which i want to upload at run time.so my question is how to get the filepath of pdf at run time on selecting pdf file from sdcard so that i can use the path to upload that file.  thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this is what i use to get video files. you can change them for pdf.

```
private static final int SELECT_VIDEO_DIALOG = 1;
```

...

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("video/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"), SELECT_VIDEO_DIALOG);
```

and in your onActivityResult

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent result) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_VIDEO) {
            Uri data = result.getData();

            if(data.getLastPathSegment().endsWith("mp4")){
                Player.show(this, data);    
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid file type", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

this will open file manager applicatons like FileEexpert, astro, Gallery ... and you can browse and select the file.

Comment: thank you for quick reply it working nicely just i changed the setType as application/pdf.thank you very much once again.