# Uploading images to remote MySQL server

Tags: java, android, mysql, multithreading, android-asynctask

Good day. Please can someone help me with this?
Is it possible to upload images from android to remote database?
I'm able to communicate with my remote database and perform simple operations like read, write, and delete from database but I have a problem when it comes to uploading images. I'v spent my whole day searching trying and reading methods to accomplish this from stackoverflow and other websites.
  This is what I have tried

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Bitmap bitmap1;
byte[]image1byte;
...
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_1) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
            image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            image1.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,stream);
            image1byte=stream.toByteArray();
}
```

and my AsyncTask task is;

```
 class CreateNewMessage extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        pDialog=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Uploading Message...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String topic=inputTopic.getText().toString();
        String message=inputMessage.getText().toString();
        String other=inputOther.getText().toString();
        List<NameValuePair>params=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("topic",topic));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message",message));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("details",details));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",sendImage1));
        JSONObject json=jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_message,"GET",params);
        try {
            response=json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d("Response",json.toString());
        return response;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Finished..Response= "+response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

but I get the following error;

```
12-12 16:22:47.017  15942-15985/com.example.mcleroy.studentboxadminpanel E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
Process: com.example.mcleroy.studentboxadminpanel, PID: 15942
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.mcleroy.studentboxadminpanel.MainActivity$CreateNewMessage.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:119)
        at com.example.mcleroy.studentboxadminpanel.MainActivity$CreateNewMessage.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:96)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-12 16:22:48.286  15942-15942/com.example.mcleroy.studentboxadminpanel E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.mcleroy.studentboxadminpanel.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4261d878 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:376)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
            at com.example.mcleroy.studentboxadminpanel.MainActivity$CreateNewMessage.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:104)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
            at com.example.mcleroy.studentboxadminpanel.MainActivity.createMessage(MainActivity.java:94)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3846)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4466)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18537)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Please please can anyone look into my code and tell me what I am not doing write, as I really need to be able to upload and download images from my app to remote database nd from remote database to app respectively. or is it impossible to accomplish this?

Here is my PHP script

```
    <?php
$servername = "xxxxx";
$username = "xxxxx";

$password = "xxxxx";

$dbname = "xxxxx";

$response = array();

$topic = $_GET['name'];
$message = $_GET['price'];
$details = $_GET['description'];
$image=$_GET['image'];


$con = mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password) or die(mysql_error());


mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
```

``` $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages(topic, messages, others,image) VALUES('$name', '$price',`` '$description','$image')"); ```

```
if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Message successfully created.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

?>

Thanks alot in advance as you try to help;

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android file uploader with server-side php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204476/android-file-uploader-with-server-side-php)

Comment: @ThePerson : I looked at that before asking. doesn't seem to solve my problems as I am trying to upload a bitmap gotten from the gallery app and not from a file